# Short 198x/199x where a man builds a threatening mechanism to prepare breakfast to a sleeping woman

Tags: identify-this-movie, short-films

Can anybody help me to identify this short film?
I saw it once in a cinema between 1980 and 1999, just before a "Delicatessen" film session. It's not animated.

**Plot**:

A man prepares a thretaening mechanism with ropes, scissors, guns, etc... inside a room or apartment, around a sleeping woman on a bed.

When the mechanism is activated (maybe by the woman's alarm clock), all the mechanisms are triggered at once, but surprisingly, none of the mechanisms harm the woman. All the mechanisms together prepare a delicious breakfast for her.

Comment: I'm curious to see how the gun figures in!

Comment: FYI, this sort of contraption is commonly called a "Rube Goldberg machine" after an early 20th century cartoonist/inventor who was famous for designing overly complex machines that perform basic tasks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg  Hopefully, that may help you identify the movie.

Comment: Wow, *I've been trying to figure this out too*... I never saw this short, but read the syopsis once and was intrigued. IIRC, there's another twist and the contraptions actually start getting out of hand and the man desperately tries to shut them off. (Do you recall if it's animated or not, BTW? I don't remember that part.)

Comment: Is not animated. Thanks for your interest, and for the Rube Goldberg machines info !

Comment: This sorta matches though the breakfast doesn't look delicious: https://youtu.be/DmJL-xzoCRs

Comment: @tohood87 Could definitely be it. A correct answer will get an extra 150 points from me, BTW. :)

Comment: @walt i added it as an answer just in case its the one  :)

Comment: @tohood87 Cool. I never actually saw it back then, so I don't know if it's right, but if the OP approves, the bounty's yours!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for the short film [**Surprise**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114583/combined) from 1995, directed by Veit Helmer.

It's about a man who sets up an elaborate and dangerous Rube Goldberg machine for his girlfriend/wife. At one point it does make her breakfast. Here it is:

Comment: I added some stuff, if that's OK. Looks like a match. +1

Comment: Thank's a lot. This short is exactly the one I was looking for!!

Comment: Real glad that's the one & happy to help :) it's a very interesting short film!